# Is there a way to refactor property file keys in whole project in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, properties-file

I'm looking for a shortcut/way that could help me to rename all the occurrence of a key in my project.

Lets say i have property file, `testdata.properties` and i have some values as given below-

```
loginpage.title = LOGIN OR CREATE AN ACCOUNT
myaccountpage.title = MY DASHBOARD
```

Now i want to rename `myaccountpage.title` to `myaccount.page.title` So it should  change all the keys in my project where i'm using this one.

Comment: You can write a program for that I think! Or use a regex in Sublime text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the text should work for this. One way to change the text occurrence using File->search (crtl+h) in Eclipse

- Search->`File` menu (Ctrl+H)
- Click on `File Search` tab
- write `myaccountpage.title` in search and click on `Enclosing Projects` tab
- Click on the Replace button
- an another dialog will appear  where you can write `myaccount.page.title`.

Comment: I think It will replace to the opened file only not in other files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the a text editor like [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/). Just open all those files in it and

[image]

Its really a great tool and has lots of other text editing features as well as add on plugins available.